# How to separate words that have uppercase and lowercase in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to separate words that have at least one uppercase letter with the lowercase. I need to take input and separate uppercase words and lowercase words and print them both. Here is my code:

```
text = input("Input your text: ")
words0 = text.strip().split()
words1 = []
words2 = []
wordslen= len(words0)
for word in words0:
    counter = 0
    for x in word:
        while counter != wordslen:
            if x.isupper():
                words1.append(word)
            else:
                words2.append(word)
            counter += 1
wordsupper = list(set(words1))
wordslower = list(set(words2))
allwords = wordsupper + wordslower

for word in allwords:
    print(word)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: could you give sample input and sample output?

Comment: like if the input is "Python and Perl are both programming languages" the code should separate "Python" and "Perl" and put it in wordupper list and rest to wordlower list. also if it was "pYthon" still it needs to put it in wordupper list.

Comment: ah - gotcha. I would add that to the question for clarity.

Comment: i am extremely new to python. so if you show me how to do and how it worked, with little more explanation i would really really appreciate

Comment: It seems like your all-lower-case question could itself do with some case detection `;-)`

Comment: use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` on Python 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = input("Input your text: ").strip().split()

lower, mixed = set(), set()
for word in words:
    if word == word.lower():
        lower.add(word)
    else:
        mixed.add(word)

print("Lowercase words: " + ", ".join(lower))
print("Mixed- and uppercase words: " + ", ".join(mixed))
```

which runs like:

```
Input your text: This is a Perl and Python party.
Lowercase words: a, and, is, party.
Mixed- and uppercase words: This, Python, Perl
```

Answer (score 1):

this is similar to previous posts, but uses `map()` instead of `for word in words:`

```
text = raw_input("Input your text: ")
words = text.strip().split()

upper = []
lower = []
def sort_word(word):
    if word.lower() == word:
        lower.append(word)
    else:
        upper.append(word)

map(sort_word, words)
```

Comment: ... you do realize you're putting lowercase words in `upper` and mixed- and upper-case words in `lower`, right?

Answer (score 1):

To separate words that have only lowercase characters from the rest:

```
text = raw_input('Input text: ')

lower, rest = set(), set()
for word in text.split():
    (lower if word == word.lower() else rest).add(word)
print(lower)
print(rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
text = input("Input your text: ")
words = text.strip().split()
wordslower = []
wordsupper = []

for word in words:
    # if the word is the same as word.lower() that means all the
    # characters are lower case.  Also, don't add duplicates to
    # the list.
    if word == word.lower():
        if word not in wordslower:
            wordslower.append(word)
    else: # The word has at least one capital letter
        if word not in wordsupper:
            wordsupper.append(word)

print(wordslower)
print(wordsupper)
```

Comment: Rather than doing a membership check for each word, why not use a set? Doesn't seem like order would matter in this case, so just do `wordslower = set(); wordsupper = set()` and replace `list.append` with `set.add`

Comment: Sure, you could do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def check(word):
    for k in word:
        if k != k.lower(): #If the letter is capitalized
            return True
    return False

text = input('Text: ')
text = text.strip().split()

wordsupper = []
wordslower = []

for k in text:
    if check(k) == True:
        wordsupper.append(k)
    else:
        wordslower.append(k)

print(wordslower)
print(wordsupper)
```